# Android studio .gradle in red, how to fix it?

Tags: android

I got on android studio in project files a .gradle paste in red.

I know there's a similar question of this one, but i didn't understand how to fix it.
.gradle in red:

[image]

Hope you could help me.

Samyueru

Comment: Do you have a problem compiling or anything? That's just how Android Studio colours "Excluded" folders by default, meaning build folders and such.

Answer (score 5):

It basically means that the folder is excluded. check **settings >> directories**, or just press right click on this folder and look at "**Mark directory as**" menu item.

Comment: kindly share a screenshot of settings option.

Comment: refer to this link https://plus.google.com/+AlexRuiz/posts/JpgmdTyyxxo      It will surely resolve your issue.

Comment: @Samyueru I cannot see the image. have you tried going to the link I've just posted

Comment: I putted the image on the answer field

Comment: go to this link  plus.google.com/+AlexRuiz/posts/JpgmdTyyxxo